# Upper bounding $\text{Var}(\max_i \{X_i + c_i\})$ using $\text{Var}(\max_i \{X_i \})$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance

Let $c_i$ be arbitrary positive constants. Is there a way to upper bound $\text{Var}(\max_i \{X_i + c_i\})$ by some constant multiple of $\text{Var}(\max_i \{X_i \})$ that is independent of the values of $c_i$'s?

My gut feeling is that this is possible because the $c_i$'s are constants and they do not affect the randomness seen by the variance.

(In my application, $X_i = \sum_{k=1}^i Y_k$ where $Y_i$ are subexponential iid random variables.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_m = \sum_{k=1}^m Y_k$ where $Y_k$ are subexponential i.i.d random variables of negative mean $-1$. Then
$$\text{Var}(\max_{m \in [1,n]}   \{X_m \})=O(1)$$
(This is easiest to see if $Y_k$ are uniform on $[-2,0]$, say).
However, if we take $c_m=m$, then
$$\text{Var}(\max_{m \in [1,n]}  \{X_m + c_m\})$$
is of order $n$.